# gzipping a file with nodejs streams causes memory leaks

Tags: node.js, stream, zlib

I'm trying to do what should be seemingly quite simple: take a file with filename X, and create a gzipped version as "X.gz". Nodejs's zlib module does not come with a convenient zlib.gzip(infile, outfile), so I figured I'd use an input stream, an output stream, and a zlib gzipper, then pipe them:

```
var zlib = require("zlib"),
    zipper = zlib.createGzip(),
    fs = require("fs");

var tryThing = function(logfile) {
  var input = fs.createReadStream(logfile, {autoClose: true}),
       output = fs.createWriteStream(logfile + ".gz");

  input.pipe(zipper).pipe(output);

  output.on("end", function() {
    // delete original file, it is no longer needed
    fs.unlink(logfile);

    // clear listeners
    zipper.removeAllListeners();
    input.removeAllListeners();
  });
}
```

however, every time I run this function, the memory footprint of Node.js grows by about 100kb. Am I forgetting to tell the streams they should just kill themselves off again because they won't be needed any longer?

Or, alternatively, is there a way to just gzip a file without bothering with streams and pipes? I tried googling for "node.js gzip a file" but it's just links to the API docs, and stack overflow questions on gzipping streams and buffers, not how to just gzip a file.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to properly `unpipe` and `close` the stream. Simply `removeAllListeners()` may not be enough to clean things up. As streams may be waiting for more data (and thus staying alive in memory unnecessarily.)

Also you're not closing the output stream as well and IMO I'd listen on the input stream's `end` instead of the output.

```
// cleanup
input.once('end', function() {
  zipper.removeAllListeners();
  zipper.close();
  zipper = null;
  input.removeAllListeners();
  input.close();
  input = null;
  output.removeAllListeners();
  output.close();
  output = null;
});
```

Also I don't think the stream returned from `zlib.createGzip()` can be shared once ended. You should create a new one at every iteration of `tryThing`:

```
var input = fs.createReadStream(logfile, {autoClose: true}),
  output = fs.createWriteStream(logfile + ".gz")
  zipper = zlib.createGzip(); 

input.pipe(zipper).pipe(output);
```

Havn't tested this tho as I don't have a memory profile tool nearby right now.

Comment: good points, although if close() gets called, removealllisteneres and null assignment are not necessary anymore. I ended up going for a straight in.pipe(out) and reassigning that every cycle, then gzipping the finalised out file using the less pipe-y readfile/gzip/writefile/unlink but you still get an upvote for a useful answer.